# createCorrect view returns ENVELOPE_CANNOT_CORRECT_INVALID_STATE on 'sent' envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to get a correction view for an envelope in the live environment that is definitely in the 'Sent' status.  The account I've logged in with has the canSendEnvelope = true setting, and I am able to generate a sender view url and successfully send an envelope.  This is an admin account.

However, correction views do not work.  I get back the error code ENVELOPE_CANNOT_CORRECT_INVALID_STATE with the message: "This account may not have 'correct' permission, or the envelope state is not 'sent' or 'delivered'."

I have looked through all of the settings returned by Users::getSettings for this user, and none of them contain the word "correct".  I also checked an account that I was using the sandbox account, and it also does not have anything about a "Correct" setting, though correction views worked there.

Is there a different way to detect if a user should be able to create correction views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting `Allow Envelope Correct` in the DS Internal Admin which cannot be seen by DocuSign users. Please contact your DocuSign Account Manager and he/she will be able to enable this flag if its not enabled. Its always enabled in Demo but few DS subscription plans do not have this feature enabled.

Comment: But is there any way to detect this setting through the API?  I would like to be able to hide the correction option from users of my application if it's not set.

Comment: I think `GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings` should return `allowEnvelopeCorrect` as true or false.